# Docker nginx image can't read a file located in a docker volume

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-volume

I created a docker volume on my host

```
docker volume create test
```

and I tried the official nginx image from docker hub :

```
docker run --name test-nginx-volume -v c:\www\test-nginx\:/usr/share/nginx/html --mount source=test,target=/usr/share/nginx/html/images -d -p 8080:80 nginx
```

Inside my C:\www\test-nginx I just created an index.html file (content is just a Test !) which is displayed properly when I go on http://localhost:8080

Inside my test volume, I have an image file test.png but when I go on http://localhost:8080/images/test.png  I have an http 200 response with a blank page and a javascript error saying : `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'src' of null"`

If I try http://localhost:8080/images/xyz.png then I receive an http 400 response which is normal and logic.

What am I missing about the usage of my volume so that nginx can display the image ?

Comment: When you go to `http://localhost/images/test.png` without a port number, it will hit whatever is listening on port 80 on your host machine. Nginx is listening on port 8080, so it's not nginx that's giving you the error message. It's something else you have running that's listening on port 80.

Comment: sorry, my bad, I meant when I go to http://localhost:8080/images/test.png

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error, but I can't. It works as it should for me. Are you sure that your volume contains the image?

Comment: Well ... I did it again from the beginning and indeed, my image is being displayed. I think I did it too fast cause I was trying to reproduce the issue from  my current project that is way more complicated. Thanks a lot @HansKilian. So it means there is something wrong in my original project

Comment: That's fine :) It happens to all of us. Glad you got it working.